# Create worksheet multiply times for the same type using VBA macro

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to create worksheet multiply times for different items specified in sheet1 using VBA macro.

For example, I have a table in sheet1 with some test type and the times tested.

```
Test Type          Times Tested
   a                     1  
   b                     2  
   c                     1  
   d                     2
```

I want macro to create sets of worksheets with the following names: a_1, b_1, b_2, c_1, d_1, and d_2 based on the test type and the times tested.

Following is the code I have written only for the test type, which only creates sheets with names: a, b, c, and d

```
Sub GenerateWorksheets()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect the name prefix and the number of suffixes into an array.

```
Sub GenerateWorksheets()
    Dim a as long, b as long, nams as variant

    with workSheets("Sheet1")
        nams = .Range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value2
    end with

    For a =lbound(nams, 1) to ubound(nams, 1)
        For b =1 to nams(a, 2)
            with workSheets.Add( after:=workSheets(workSheets.Count))
                .name = nams(a, 1) & "_" & b
            end with
        next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: The code creates worksheets with names a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2, d_1, and d_2.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it looked funny the first time around. Should be fixed now.